# good C# interview questions book

Tags: c#

Please suggest me a good C# interview questions book

Comment: This could mean anything from a good book to get better at interviewing or being interviewed or even a good book to read during an interview. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jon Skeet's C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) is a great book to make you more experienced if you're familiar only with the basics of C# 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I remember that When I read [.netFramework Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-536&locale=en-us) I foundthat a good book to get started like a charm.

This book is a necessary book for those who are interested to be a Microsoft Proficient (MCTS or MCPD), So I recommand youto read this one.

Comment: yeah, I agree, it helps me a lot on my interview

Answer (score 3):

[Schaum's Outline of Programming with C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071353461).

You'll note that I said "C++", not "C#". The language hardly matters; any of the coding questions in a basic C or C++ text can be easily adapted to pretty much any language. Sometimes when I'm looking for inspiration for technical questions I just open that thing up at random and see what sorts of questions I come across.

Comment: @Eric Funny you mention this I recently spoke to an ex-MS developer who said the interview process in Redmond is not only lengthy, but quite intense.